# jQuery button that hides container

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I'm building fieldset that has a button in it that fade away the whole fieldset. Is this possible? I started with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js" ></script>
<script>
 Some script here
</script>
<fieldset>
    <legend><b>Fieldset</b></legend>
    <p>Dissapering fieldset</p>
    <input type="button" onclick=" Some event here" value="Hide this fieldset"></input>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: What's with all the extra spaces in tags?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#button_id').click(function() {
    $('#fieldset_id').hide();
});
```

or

```
$('#button_id').click(function() {
    $('#fieldset_id').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("fieldset").css("display", "none");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("buttonId").click(function() {
  $("yourfieldSetId").fadeOut("slow");
});
});
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Run this modified version of your code.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js" ></script>  

</head>

<body>


<fieldset id="test">  

<legend><b>Fieldset</b></legend>  

<p>Dissapering fieldset</p>  

<input type="button" onclick="$('#test').hide('slow')" value="Hide this fieldset"></input>  

</fieldset>  

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/YAJ4u/

As per my solution in JS Fiddle, give the button id `hider` and then:

```
$('#hider').click(function() {
     $('#test').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty straightforward to me. Just give the fieldset an id of say fieldset,then

```
$(function(){

    $('#fieldset').click(function(){
     $(this).fadeOut();
    }  
}
```